# hsqldb with spring and hibernate where is the data from data file on start up

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hsqldb

There are a lot of examples of this and this is sort of a hybrid of those. So this is a console app using a classpath application context. This is a small amount of data but I am wondering, where are the records that are in the data file when the test runs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN"
    "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">

<beans>

        <bean id="productDao" class="com.practice.HibernateProductDaoImpl">
            <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="customerDao" class="com.practice.HibernateCustomerDaoImpl">
            <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
        </bean>

    <!-- HSQLDB Data Source -->        
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:file:naturalfoods" />
        <property name="username" value="sa" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="5" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="10" />
        <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true" />
        <property name="maxOpenPreparedStatements" value="10" />
    </bean> 

    <!-- Hibernate Session Factory  -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.practice.Category</value>
                <value>com.practice.Product</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

some java code

```
package com.practice;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="PRODUCT")
public class Product {
  public Product(int i, String string, int j) {
    this.id=(long) i;
    this.productName=string;
    this.productInventory=i;
  }

  public Product() {
    super();
  }

  @Id
  @Column(name="PRODUCT_ID")
  private Long id;

  @Column(name="PRODUCT_NAME")
  private String productName;

  @Column(name="PRODUCT_PRICE")
  private Double productPrice;

  @Column(name="PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION")
  private String productDescription;

  @Column(name="PRODUCT_INVENTORY")
  private Integer productInventory;


}


@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:applicationContext.xml" })
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = true)
@Transactional
public class TestDBConnection {

  private static ApplicationContext context;
  private HibernateProductDaoImpl productDao;

  @BeforeClass
  public static void setUpClass(){
    context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:applicationContext.xml");
  }

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    productDao =  (HibernateProductDaoImpl)context.getBean("productDao");
    Session session = productDao.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    ClassMetadata data = productDao.getSessionFactory().getClassMetadata(Product.class);
    for(String string:data.getPropertyNames())
      System.out.println("name " + string);
    Object object = session.get("com.practice.Product", 1L);
    Product product = new Product(10,"bahhh",1);
    session.save(product);
    session.flush();
    session.clear();
    Query query = session.createQuery("From java.lang.Object");
    System.out.print(query.list().get(0));
  }

  @Test
  public void test() {
    fail("Not yet implemented");
  }

}
```

Here is naturalfoods.script

```
CREATE SCHEMA PUBLIC AUTHORIZATION DBA

CREATE MEMORY TABLE CATEGORY(CATEGORY_ID BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY(START WITH 1) NOT NULL 
PRIMARY KEY,CATEGORY_NAME VARCHAR(255))


CREATE MEMORY TABLE PRODUCT(PRODUCT_ID BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY(START WITH 1) NOT NULL 
PRIMARY KEY,PRODUCT_NAME VARCHAR(255),PRODUCT_PRICE DOUBLE,PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(255),
PRODUCT_INVENTORY INTEGER)

ALTER TABLE CATEGORY ALTER COLUMN CATEGORY_ID RESTART WITH 6

ALTER TABLE PRODUCT ALTER COLUMN PRODUCT_ID RESTART WITH 7

CREATE USER SA PASSWORD ""

GRANT DBA TO SA

SET WRITE_DELAY 10

SET SCHEMA PUBLIC
```

Then naturalfoods.data

```
INSERT INTO PRODUCT VALUES(1,'Apple',0.25E0,'Food',10)

INSERT INTO PRODUCT VALUES(2,'Orange',0.5E0,'Food',10)

INSERT INTO PRODUCT VALUES(3,'Banana',0.75E0,'Food',0)

INSERT INTO PRODUCT VALUES(4,'Peas',1.5E0,'Food',10)

INSERT INTO PRODUCT VALUES(5,'Carrots',1.0E0,'Food',10)

INSERT INTO CATEGORY VALUES(1,'Fruit')

INSERT INTO CATEGORY VALUES(2,'Vegetables')

INSERT INTO CATEGORY VALUES(3,'Meat')

INSERT INTO CATEGORY VALUES(4,'Dairy')
```

Here is some log4j output:

```
name productDescription
name productInventory
name productName
name productPrice
[2014-02-24 15:34:22,512] [DEBUG] [org.hibernate.SQL] [select product0_.PRODUCT_ID as PRODUCT1_1_0_, product0_.PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION as PRODUCT2_1_0_, product0_.PRODUCT_INVENTORY as PRODUCT3_1_0_, product0_.PRODUCT_NAME as PRODUCT4_1_0_, product0_.PRODUCT_PRICE as PRODUCT5_1_0_ from PRODUCT product0_ where product0_.PRODUCT_ID=?]
Hibernate: select product0_.PRODUCT_ID as PRODUCT1_1_0_, product0_.PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION as PRODUCT2_1_0_, product0_.PRODUCT_INVENTORY as PRODUCT3_1_0_, product0_.PRODUCT_NAME as PRODUCT4_1_0_, product0_.PRODUCT_PRICE as PRODUCT5_1_0_ from PRODUCT product0_ where product0_.PRODUCT_ID=?
[2014-02-24 15:34:22,552] [DEBUG] [org.hibernate.SQL] [insert into PRODUCT (PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION, PRODUCT_INVENTORY, PRODUCT_NAME, PRODUCT_PRICE, PRODUCT_ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
Hibernate: insert into PRODUCT (PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION, PRODUCT_INVENTORY, PRODUCT_NAME, PRODUCT_PRICE, PRODUCT_ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
[2014-02-24 15:34:23,925] [DEBUG] [org.hibernate.SQL] [select product0_.PRODUCT_ID as PRODUCT1_1_, product0_.PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION as PRODUCT2_1_, product0_.PRODUCT_INVENTORY as PRODUCT3_1_, product0_.PRODUCT_NAME as PRODUCT4_1_, product0_.PRODUCT_PRICE as PRODUCT5_1_ from PRODUCT product0_]
Hibernate: select product0_.PRODUCT_ID as PRODUCT1_1_, product0_.PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION as PRODUCT2_1_, product0_.PRODUCT_INVENTORY as PRODUCT3_1_, product0_.PRODUCT_NAME as PRODUCT4_1_, product0_.PRODUCT_PRICE as PRODUCT5_1_ from PRODUCT product0_
[2014-02-24 15:34:24,005] [DEBUG] [org.hibernate.SQL] [select category0_.CATEGORY_ID as CATEGORY1_0_, category0_.CATEGORY_NAME as CATEGORY2_0_ from CATEGORY category0_]
Hibernate: select category0_.CATEGORY_ID as CATEGORY1_0_, category0_.CATEGORY_NAME as CATEGORY2_0_ from CATEGORY category0_
com.practice.Product@1784427
```

That's not the extact data and script but close. I am just wodering why there was only 1 product?

Comment: How are naturalfoods.data and naturalfoods.script being run?

Comment: So I changed this a to combine *.script and *.data into *.script. The key to hsqldb start up was <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:file:naturalfoods" /> with the 'file' option being set to mem was another option. I place naturalfoods.script under src/main/resouces/. I thought hsqldb ran every SQL command in the file on start up including the insert statements. So I had expected date to be there off an initial read.

Comment: So were you able to get this working yet, or still trying?

Answer (score 0):

I would expect there to only be one product.  You only have one test.  That test runs the `@Before` method once, which creates and saves one and only one product.

If you are finding that there is only one product after multiple test runs, then you probably want to change your DB script to not create `memory` tables.

Comment: I tried adding commit after the inserts. No effect. I read up on setting create text table opposed to create memory table but that uses csv files was my understanding. I thought 'mem' vs 'file' for the url option meant that 'file' would read through the intialization script and perform crud operations.

Comment: So I believe I misread the original set up and missed the fine print that 'mem' guarantees the tables to be empty. Use 'file' if you want data to be in the table after multiple sessions.